# sql server acumulación de datos en un solo campo con update

Tags: sql, update, server

estoy en un ST donde realiza una tarea de clasificación y dependiendo de una condición se actualiza un campo donde va el resultado, el tema está que existen registros donde aplican en más de una condición y las actualizacion se van pisando, y como son muchas las actualizacion no quiero generar tantos campos, la idea es que se bajan agregando al mismo campo.

```
update [AUXILIAR1] Set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION'
where tipopersona = 'J'  

update [AUXILIAR1] Set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'HUMANO'
where tipopersona = 'F'  

update [AUXILIAR1] Set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'OTRO_CAMPO'
where OTROCAMPO = 'X'
```

Ejemplo1: si un registro tiene `[tipopersona] = 'J'` y también `[OTROCAMPO] = 'X'` deberia dar como resultado `[CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION - OTRO_CAMPO'`

Ejemplo2: si un registro tiene `[tipopersona] = 'J'` debería dar como resultado `[CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION'`

Ejemplo3: si un registro tiene `[tipopersona] = 'J' y también [OTROCAMPO] = 'X'` y `[tipopersona] = 'F'` debería dar como resultado `[CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION - HUMANO - OTRO_CAMPO'`

Gracias.

Comment: tipopersona solo puede tener un valor a la vez, no puede ser J y F.

Comment: En efecto, como dice @LuisCazares el tercer ejemplo no hace sentido

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es bastante simple, solo tienes que añadir condiciones al `WHERE` para encontrar los registros que quieres actualizar mediante operadores lógicos `AND` o `OR`.

> Ejemplo1: [tipopersona] = 'J' y también [OTROCAMPO] = 'X' debería dar
> como resultado [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION - OTRO_CAMPO'

```
update [AUXILIAR1] Set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION - OTRO_CAMPO'
where tipopersona = 'J' 
AND [OTROCAMPO] = 'X'
```

> Ejemplo2: si un registro tiene [tipopersona] = 'J' debería dar como
> resultado [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION'

```
update [AUXILIAR1] Set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION'
where tipopersona = 'J'
```

Como puedes ver la segunda opción pisa la anterior, es decir que actualiza también los registros de la sentencia anterior, aunque sin consecuencias.

> Ejemplo3: si un registro tiene [tipopersona] = 'J' y también
> [OTROCAMPO] = 'X' y [tipopersona] = 'F' debería dar como resultado
> [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = 'ASOCIACION - HUMANO - OTRO_CAMPO'

Un registro (una fila) solo tendrá un valor en la columna [tipopersona], por lo que no es un caso real.

Comment: Gracias por responder, cometí el error de la omisión que en este caso es fundamental, las actualizaciones al  campo " [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] " no son de procesos seguidos, o cronológicos, por tal motivo se me complica hacer un case o una anidación de if.  ese campo podría tener una o 15 concatenaciones, es por eso que no me conviene generar 15 campos porque la mayoría de los resultados podrían contener uno o dos resultados, pero los necesito a todos. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes componer el campo valiéndote de una serie de sentencias `case` que evalúa las condiciones de cada campo. El resultado final es la concatenación de estas sentencias, por ejemplo:

```
update [AUXILIAR1]
   set [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] = substring(ltrim(
           case tipopersona
             when 'J' then '- ASOCIACION'
             when 'F' then '- HUMANO'
             else ''
           end
         + ' '
         + case OTROCAMPO
             when 'X' then '- OTRO_CAMPO'
             else ''
           end
       ), 3, 1000)
 where tipopersona in ('J', 'F')
    or OTROCAMPO = 'X'
```

Si observas, utilizo `ltrim` para eliminar cualquier caracter que quede al inicio y siempre agrego un guión adicional, que luego se quita con la llamada a `substring`. Eso me permite agegar espacios y separadores.

Comment: Gracias por responder, cometí el error de la omisión que en este caso es fundamental, las actualizaciones al  campo " [CAMPO_SENSIBLE] " no son de procesos seguidos, o cronologicos, por tal motivo se me complica hacer un case o una anidación de if.  ese campo podría tener una o 15 concatenaciones, es por eso que no me conviene generar 15 campos porque la mayoría de los resultados podrían contener uno o dos resultados, pero los necesito a todos. Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir con que no son de procesos seguidos o cronológicos. Creo que debes plantear una nueva pregunta y explicar con claridad (y ejemplos) cuál es el problema. Esta respuesta es correcta para el problema que plantea esta pregunta.